# `STACK-FULL` and `QUEUE-FULL` with worst-case $\Theta(1)$

Tags: stacks, linked-lists, queues

There are two problems in CLRS about implementing stacks and queues with singly linked lists. I know the solutions, I know how `STACK-EMPTY` and `PUSH` and `POP` and `QUEUE-EMPTY` and `ENQUEUE` and `DEQUEUE` are defined. But can we define `STACK-FULL` and `QUEUE-FULL` with worst-case $\Theta(1)$ time? One idea is to set a counter and increment or decrement it whenever we add or delete elements but I don't want to use some extra information or add something to the problem. I just want to use the information (like attributes) relevant to singly linked lists only.

Comment: You have to add this additional information. Its not even a lot of information, and its pretty standard to keep it even in practical implementations

Comment: @nirshahar So there is no other way? That's the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to add additional information.  There is no way to meet your requirements without adding additional information.